# MySQL plugin for Qt 4.8.0 build fails

Tags: mysql, qt

I am trying to build the MySQL plugin for a Qt project. I am following the instructions given elsewhere, but it appears that the makefile which is generated by qmake has an error and the nmake to generate the DLL fails.

Does anyone have an alternate procedure?

And does anyone know why we simply can't download the MySQL DLL for this? Why does everybody have to build it?

Here is the process;

```
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=c:/'Program Files'/MySQL/'Connector C 6.0.2'/include" "LIBS+=-Lc:/'Program Files'/MySQL/'Connector C 6.0.2'/lib/debug " mysql.pro

c:\QtSDK\QtSources\4.8.0\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>nmake debug

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
    "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe" -f Makefile.Debug

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    rc -D_DEBUG -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_DLL -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3
DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -fo debug\qsqlmysqld_resource.res qsqlmysqld_resource.rc

'rc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'rc' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Comment: "Why does everybody have to build it?" Because not everyone uses Windows.  Post the build error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I solved the problem of building the plugin with nmake, it didn't result in a plugin that Qt recognized.

Instead I built the plugins using QtCreator and the project file included in (Your Qt source folder path/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql

The .pro file has to be edited so that the include and lib paths match that for your MySQL install. The entries that were in the .pro file included spaces in the paths, but this did not build. I had to take all spaces out of the mysql paths to get it to build. I dragged MySQL out of the "Program Files (x86)" to C: and removed spaces from the folder names.

Next, the debug build specifies -llibmysqld which doesn't seem to exist anymore. I changed it to -llibmysql (same as the release) and then both dlls built fine.

I used Qt Creator 2.6.2, Qt 4.8.4. The resulting dlls are working with Qt projects built
under Visual Studio 2010 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

I would hazard a guess that you're building from the normal command prompt/window and not the Visual Studio version. That would mean that probably not all paths are set correctly and it cannot find the rc command.

So try to build again, but this time from the [Visual Studio command prompt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You will find it under "Visual Studio Tools" in your Visual Studio entry in the start menu for example.

You could alternatively run [VCVARS32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to set up all appropriate paths in your regular command prompt, but there is really no need.

Comment: Thank you for that. That was correct. However, using the VS command prompt results in many undefined references such as "mysql_stmt_result_metadata4". Trying it on previous versions 4.7.1 or  4.7.3 give different undefined references, but about the same number. I also tried building with mingw32 and the QT console. They gave the same errors.