# Compiling MySQL Plugin for Qt 4.8.1 on Windows with Visual Studio 2010 C++

Tags: mysql, qt, plugins

The Qt project does not provide MySQL [database drivers for the Qt SQL module](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html) so one would have to use ODBC or [compile the plugin manually](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#building-the-plugins-manually).
I am trying the latter.
I have been using the pre-built Qt 4.8.1 with VS 2010 and fail to find the plugin's project file (mysql.pro) in "C:/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.1/src/sql/drivers/mysql/" as numerous tutorials use. There is qsql_mysql.pri with the following contents:

```
HEADERS += $$PWD/qsql_mysql.h
SOURCES += $$PWD/qsql_mysql.cpp

# modified! I added these:
#INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/include" 
#LIBS += "C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/lib/libmysql.lib"

unix {
    isEmpty(QT_LFLAGS_MYSQL) {
        !contains(LIBS, .*mysqlclient.*):!contains(LIBS, .*mysqld.*) {
            use_libmysqlclient_r:LIBS += -lmysqlclient_r
            else:LIBS += -lmysqlclient
        }
    } else {
        LIBS *= $$QT_LFLAGS_MYSQL
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS *= $$QT_CFLAGS_MYSQL
    }
} else {
    !contains(LIBS, .*mysql.*):!contains(LIBS, .*mysqld.*):LIBS += -llibmysql
}
```

Building it results in the following errors:

```
release\moc_qsql_mysql.cpp(45) : warning C4273: 'QMYSQLDriver::qt_static_metacall': Inconsistent DLL-binding.
        C:/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.1/src/sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.h(104): See previous definition of 'qt_static_metacall'
release\moc_qsql_mysql.cpp(57) : warning C4273: 'staticMetaObjectExtraData': Inconsistent DLL-Binding.
        C:/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.1/src/sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.h(104): See previous definition of 'private: static QMetaObjectExtraData const QMYSQLDriver::staticMetaObjectExtraData'
release\moc_qsql_mysql.cpp(57) : error C2491: 'QMYSQLDriver::staticMetaObjectExtraData': Definition of static member for dllimport not valid
release\moc_qsql_mysql.cpp(61) : warning C4273: 'staticMetaObject': Inconsistent DLL-binding.
        C:/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.1/src/sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.h(104): See previous definition of 'public: static QMetaObject const QMYSQLDriver::staticMetaObject'
release\moc_qsql_mysql.cpp(61) : error C2491: 'QMYSQLDriver::staticMetaObject': Definition of static member for dllimport not valid
release\moc_qsql_mysql.cpp(71) : warning C4273: 'QMYSQLDriver::metaObject': Inconsistent DLL-binding.
        C:/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.1/src/sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.h(104): See previous definition of 'metaObject'
release\moc_qsql_mysql.cpp(76) : warning C4273: 'QMYSQLDriver::qt_metacast': Inconsistent DLL-binding.
        C:/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.1/src/sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.h(104): See previous definition of 'qt_metacast'
release\moc_qsql_mysql.cpp(84) : warning C4273: 'QMYSQLDriver::qt_metacall': Inconsistent DLL-binding.
        C:/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.1/src/sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.h(104): See previous definition of 'qt_metacall'
c:\QtSDK\QtSources\4.8.1\src\sql\drivers\mysql\qsql_mysql.cpp(47) : fatal error C1083: File (Include) could not be opened: "qsqlerror.h": No such file or directory
```

This also happens when I try a manually crafted mysql.pro that is pretty much identical:

```
LIBS += "C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/lib/libmysql.lib"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/include/"

SOURCES += "C:/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.1/src/sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.cpp"
HEADERS += "C:/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.1/src/sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.h"
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665119/error-compiling-qt-mysql-driver) might be an version closer to the original.

Another question regarding the licensing of this approach: does building this plugin using Qt sources require publishing the sources used and / or are there limitations using the module as dynamic library (no static linking allowed for commercial purposes with Qt open source).

Comment: Looks like I got the wrong path!
See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15391923
C:\QtSDK\QtSources\4.8.1\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql

Answer (score 0):

I got the wrong path!
The file mysql.pro exists in C:\QtSDK\QtSources\4.8.1\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql

```
TARGET = qsqlmysql

# added these two lines after copying from
# C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6
LIBS += lib/libmysql.lib
INCLUDEPATH += include/

SOURCES = main.cpp
include(../../../sql/drivers/mysql/qsql_mysql.pri)

include(../qsqldriverbase.pri)
```

Now I could build the plugin.
I copied the files to C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\plugins\sqldrivers

Run MySQL as Admin with

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini"
```

But even though I copied the DLLs into Qt's plugin directory

```
C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\plugins\sqldrivers
```

they were not found:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC3 QODBC
QSqlError(-1, "Driver not loaded", "Driver not loaded")
```

This Answer [Qt 4.8.0 - MySQL Driver not listed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618182/qt-4-8-0-mysql-driver-not-listed?rq=1) has the solution:

> To use it just make sure that you have the path where you find
>   libmysql.dll (usually C:\mysql\bin) as a part of the environment
>   variable PATH.

Or just copy the DLL into the Qt project dir root..